# Countifs in Power BI power query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm struggling on this issue for more than 2 days, I did a lot of search but still cannot find the solution. Is there any way in power query which is similar to Countifs in excel? Please find my sample data below

Table 1

```
Id           Countifs
A01          =COUNTIS(Table2[Id],[Id],Table2[Categorisation],"CORE"
A02
A03
A04
A05
```

Table 2

```
Id    Title       Categorisation
A01   Super        CORE
A01   Saving       Complex
A02   Saving       Complex
A02   Super        CORE
A03   Insurance    Redundant
```

Thanks very much

Comment: Do you have relation between tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have relation between table 1 and 2 through ID column, you can try this below **Measure** to get your desired output-

```
Measure = 

var N =
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('Table 2'[Id]),
    FILTER(
        'Table 2',
        'Table 2'[Categorisation] = "CORE"
    )
)

return if(ISBLANK(N), 0, N)
```

Output-

[image]

**UPDATE**

Code for column-

```
Column = 

var current_id = 'Table 1'[Id]

var N =
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        all('Table 2'),
        'Table 2'[Id] = current_id 
            && 'Table 2'[Categorisation] = "CORE"
    )
    
)+0  

return if(N>1,1,N)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it works. Just wondering if we can use "add column" instead of measure? if yes, how can I do it?

Comment: Let me check. And please don't forget to accept an answer and put an upvote when it helped and worked :)

Comment: @KarenZ please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data in Table2 is loaded as query with that name, in powerquery, bring in data from Table1 and add column .. custom column...  with formula:

```
=  List.Count(Table.SelectRows(Table2,(C) => [Id] = C[Id] and C[Categorisation] = "CORE")[Id])
```

Comment: Hi Horseyride, thanks for your help. But I got a error "A cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation." I'm pretty new to Power BI, I have no idea how to solve it, could you please help?

Comment: Sorry Horseyride, My bad. This is my other table's issue, and it's solved. Thanks so much for your solution. It works.